# How to reduce app size in Ionic2?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, android-install-apk

I am new to Ionic, recently I developed One app.But my app size was 8mb.
How should I reduce app size,and I am not using any Images and plugins also, but it took 8mb size. please help me.

Answer (score 6):

For production builds you can use `ionic cordova build [android/ios] --prod --release`. This **can** reduced the size of your application.

The `prod` and `release` flags will minify code and remove debugging utilities.

Documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/#production-builds

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of **[$ ionic cordova build](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/build/)** options

- **--no-build** - Do not invoke an Ionic build
- **--prod** - Build the application for production
- **--aot** - Perform ahead-of-time compilation for this build
- **--minifyjs** - Minify JS for this build
- **--minifycss** - Minify CSS for this build
- **--optimizejs** - Perform JS optimizations for this build
- ...

For example: `ionic cordova build android --prod --aot`

Comment: Thanks for your reply